# How to set default scroll position for LazyColumn without any feedback or animation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I want my LazyColumn to show items in the list from the middle so I can scroll up or down. I used rememberLazyListState but it has some delay and I don't want the scrolling action to happen in the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val scrollState = rememberLazyListState(initialFirstVisibleItemIndex = 50)
val scrollState = rememberLazyListState(initialFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset = 3700)
```

You can use anyone of the parameter to start from a default position if you have `100` items in the list you could set `initialFirstVisibleItemIndex = 50` so it starts from middle also you can set the `offset` but just use any one of them.

It works for me without any delay

Comment: It works for the first list but when I update the list, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Ok what do you mean by updating the list? Do you want to snap to the middle every time an item is added or removed?

Comment: @Mehranjp73 that's what the parameter name also says it's `initial` but why would you want the list to be always at middle, what you could do is call `scrollToItem` method every time list is updated.

Comment: It scrolls using scrollToItem but it shows the moving of the list.